# Refresh datagrid data from SQLite Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, datagrid, refresh

can i ask you about my problem.
I'm using Synfusion lib to make datagrid and i have trouble with updating rows there.
Also, I'm using datapager, because it cause lags when scrolling that much data on my device.

I have datasource set on SQLite Db on device and setting source to datapager and datagrid throught it.
This is the way, how I'm doing it.

```
db.Query<Prijem>("INSERT INTO Prijem(BCode,Name,FirmName,ItemCode,Price,Count) values('" + bcode + "', '" + iName + "', '" + fName + "', '" + iCode + "', '" + Price + "', 1)");

dataPager.Source = (from i in db.Table<Prijem>() orderby i.ID descending select i);
                        dataGrid.ItemsSource = dataPager.PagedSource;
```

It's there any way to refresh it other way ? Or when i refresh it, selection in grid resets and i have proble with finding solution to reselect it. Sooo is there any command for JUST REFRESH ? Thanks a lott :)

Comment: Do you mean when you refresh, the selection reset and the datagrid show the original data?

Comment: yes, but there is problem with datapager, when i use direct itemsource to DB, datagrid.refresh() helps, but with that pager..

Comment: Do you use the SfDataPager? If yes, does the data source implements ICollectionChanged interface? When it implements, the SfDataGrid will automatically refresh the view when an item is added, removed, or cleared. When you add or remove an item in ObservableCollection, it automatically refreshes the view as the ObservableCollection. That implements the INotifyCollectionChanged. But when you do the same in List, it will not refresh the view automatically. You could check the sample in the link.https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/datagrid/data-binding